# Nested Set or Adjacency List Model for file permissions (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, adjacency-list, nested-set-model, adjacency-list-model

## Question:

What design should one use when storing all user file/folder permissions in a MySQL database?

## Details:

I am having trouble deciding whether Nested Set requires far too much insert time or whether Adjacency list requires too much access time with hierarchical data. I am pretty sure Nested set takes insanely long times as the number of files/folders is increased. For example, the insertion of a node (row) requires the update of every single node after that node that is traversed. Is it possible to use string tokenization on the path (ie. `/home/user/pictures`  `-->`  `/`, `/home`, `/home/user`) and use that in a query, in what would amount to a variable length Adjancency List Model? A third option, is to have a `parent_folders` table which carries out the exact same functionality, but uses more space as opposed to more time.

Here is a minimal description of the `files` and `folders` tables:

**files:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   path                  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   r                     BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,

   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
engine=innodb;
```

**folders:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folders
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   path                  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   r                     BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,

   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
engine=innodb;
```

Here are the above two tables, modified and with a potential `parent_folders` table:

**files:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   parent_folder_id      INT NOT NULL,
   path                  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   r                     BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,

   FOREIGN KEY ( parent_folder_id ) REFERENCES folder ( id ),
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
engine=innodb;
```

**folders:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folders
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   path                  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   r                     BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,

   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
engine=innodb;
```

**parent_folders:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_folders
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   parent_folder_id      INT NOT NULL,
   folder_id             INT NOT NULL,

   FOREIGN KEY ( parent_folder_id ) REFERENCES folders ( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( folder_id ) REFERENCES folders ( id ), 
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
engine=innodb;
```

Comment: There is a third way: have you looked into [closure tables](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)?

Comment: @eggyal Is that not just storing every pair of directory/subdirectory? I thought of it, but then dismissed it as requiring far too many rows. I guess I was wrong